# Making Improvements to my SQL Architecture

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, erd

I needed to design an SQL architecture to store the various information. This is what I have came up with. Is there any SQL concepts I am missing that could drastically enhance my table creation? Maybe some tables could be divided into 2 tables or I've over complicated my design and can move two tables into one.

```
drop table film_director;
drop table film_actor;
drop table film;
drop table studio;
drop table actor;
drop table director;

CREATE TABLE studio(
  studio_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  studio_Name VARCHAR2(30),
  PRIMARY KEY(studio_ID));

CREATE TABLE film(
  film_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  studio_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  genre VARCHAR2(30),
  genre_ID NUMBER(1),
  film_Len NUMBER(3),
  film_Title VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  year_Released NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(film_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (studio_ID) REFERENCES studio);

CREATE TABLE director(
  director_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  director_fname VARCHAR2(30),
  director_lname VARCHAR2(30),
  PRIMARY KEY(director_ID));

CREATE TABLE actor(
  actor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  actor_fname VARCHAR2(15),
  actor_lname VARCHAR2(15),
  PRIMARY KEY(actor_ID));

CREATE TABLE film_actor(
  film_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  actor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(film_ID, actor_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(film_ID) REFERENCES film(film_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(actor_ID) REFERENCES actor(actor_ID));

CREATE TABLE film_director(
  film_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  director_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(film_ID, director_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(film_ID) REFERENCES film(film_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(director_ID) REFERENCES director(director_ID));

INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (1, 'Paramount');
INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (2, 'Warner Bros');
INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (3, 'Film4');
INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (4, 'Working Title Films');

INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (1, 1, 'Comedy', 1, 180, 'The Wolf Of Wall Street', 2013);
INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (2, 2, 'Romance', 2, 143, 'The Great Gatsby', 2013);
INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (3, 3, 'Science Fiction', 3, 103, 'Never Let Me Go', 2008);
INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (4, 4, 'Romance', 4, 127, 'Pride and Prejudice', 2005);

INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (1, 'Martin', 'Scorcese');
INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (2, 'Baz', 'Luhrmann');
INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (3, 'Mark', 'Romanek');
INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (4, 'Joe', 'Wright');

INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (1, 'Matthew', 'McConnaughy');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (2, 'Leonardo', 'DiCaprio');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (3, 'Margot', 'Robbie');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (4, 'Joanna', 'Lumley');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (5, 'Carey', 'Mulligan');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (6, 'Tobey', 'Maguire');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (7, 'Joel', 'Edgerton');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (8, 'Keira', 'Knightly');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (9, 'Andrew', 'Garfield');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (10, 'Sally', 'Hawkins');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (11, 'Judi', 'Dench');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (12, 'Matthew', 'Macfadyen');

INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 5);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 6);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 9);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 10);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 8);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 11);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 12);

INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (4,4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest replacing `casting` table with two tables - `filmactor`(having one row per film per actor)  and `filmdirector` (having one row per film per director). Your `casting` table has `director_id` repeating for each row for a given film which is not needed (it is also not in 3NF). Also, it will not handle the scenario properly where there are more than one director on a film (improbable but not impossible). 
Other than that the design looks fine to me.

Comment: How should I fix the casting table then? I think that was causing one of the problems for one of the queries I was trying to run because it was printing out the director's name 4 times.

Comment: I think you don't need the table `casting`. I am not sure but I think it is possible that more than one `studio` is associated with a `film`. In that case you will have to remove the `studio_id` from the table `film` and create a new table `filmstudio` associating a `film` with `studio`.