# Enhancing SQL Architecture

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, erd

I need to design a table that has no repeating groups and I think I have done that but does the table look correct with how they are linked etc. or is there anything I can improve on? I ran all the queries and I had a few repeating groups for player & manager as I had them both in a squad table so I split them into team_player & team_manager and that way one or more managers can also manage a team, vice versa with stadium etc.

```
drop table film_director;
drop table film_actor;
drop table film;
drop table studio;
drop table actor;
drop table director;

CREATE TABLE studio(
  studio_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  studio_Name VARCHAR2(30),
  PRIMARY KEY(studio_ID));

CREATE TABLE film(
  film_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  studio_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  genre VARCHAR2(30),
  genre_ID NUMBER(1),
  film_Len NUMBER(3),
  film_Title VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
  year_Released NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(film_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (studio_ID) REFERENCES studio);

CREATE TABLE director(
  director_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  director_fname VARCHAR2(30),
  director_lname VARCHAR2(30),
  PRIMARY KEY(director_ID));

CREATE TABLE actor(
  actor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  actor_fname VARCHAR2(15),
  actor_lname VARCHAR2(15),
  PRIMARY KEY(actor_ID));

CREATE TABLE film_actor(
  film_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  actor_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(film_ID, actor_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(film_ID) REFERENCES film(film_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(actor_ID) REFERENCES actor(actor_ID));

CREATE TABLE film_director(
  film_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  director_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(film_ID, director_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(film_ID) REFERENCES film(film_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(director_ID) REFERENCES director(director_ID));

INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (1, 'Paramount');
INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (2, 'Warner Bros');
INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (3, 'Film4');
INSERT INTO studio (studio_ID, studio_Name) VALUES (4, 'Working Title Films');

INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (1, 1, 'Comedy', 1, 180, 'The Wolf Of Wall Street', 2013);
INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (2, 2, 'Romance', 2, 143, 'The Great Gatsby', 2013);
INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (3, 3, 'Science Fiction', 3, 103, 'Never Let Me Go', 2008);
INSERT INTO film (film_ID, studio_ID, genre, genre_ID, film_Len, film_Title, year_Released) VALUES (4, 4, 'Romance', 4, 127, 'Pride and Prejudice', 2005);

INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (1, 'Martin', 'Scorcese');
INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (2, 'Baz', 'Luhrmann');
INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (3, 'Mark', 'Romanek');
INSERT INTO director (director_ID, director_fname, director_lname) VALUES (4, 'Joe', 'Wright');

INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (1, 'Matthew', 'McConnaughy');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (2, 'Leonardo', 'DiCaprio');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (3, 'Margot', 'Robbie');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (4, 'Joanna', 'Lumley');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (5, 'Carey', 'Mulligan');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (6, 'Tobey', 'Maguire');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (7, 'Joel', 'Edgerton');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (8, 'Keira', 'Knightly');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (9, 'Andrew', 'Garfield');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (10, 'Sally', 'Hawkins');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (11, 'Judi', 'Dench');
INSERT INTO actor (actor_ID, actor_fname, actor_lname) VALUES (12, 'Matthew', 'Macfadyen');

INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 5);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 6);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 5);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 8);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 9);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (3, 10);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 8);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 11);
INSERT INTO film_actor (film_ID, actor_ID) VALUES (4, 12);

INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO film_director (film_ID, director_ID) VALUES (4,4);
```

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged with sql and oracle... it is more a question about database design, relational database... there is nothing specifically related either to sql or to oracle

Comment: Your schema shows SYSTEM.  It is not a good idea to create tables in the system schema.  Just create a user and do your work there.  Good habits start early.

Comment: how do you know only one studio will produce a film?  Could there be co productions that imply a many studios to one film relationship?

Comment: @kevinskyI yeah, I just created a quick schema in oracle to help with the question I have to do the correct one in Visio.

Comment: Please stop changing old questions with answers. Post a new one. Please don't make new posts that are copies of old ones, just edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Improvements to my SQL Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109184/making-improvements-to-my-sql-architecture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with sdmon - since director and actor have the same attributes, it makes sense to keep them all in a single table, and assign them roles in the "facts" tables.

Can a film have more than one director? If not, then you don't need the film_director table, you just need a column for "director" in the film table. Otherwise you do need the film_director table.

Can a film be tied to more than one studio? In your model, you have a column for studio_id in the film table, but also a film_studio table. You don't need both. You need the column (but not the table) if a film is always made by a single studio. If you need to show more than one studio for a film, then you need the extra table, but not the column.

Everything else looks fine.   Good luck!

Comment: yeah that studio_id link I forgot to remove as I had just made changes but I wasn't sure whether to work off the data I was given or not but I guess now I will I was probably overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

I would only have 1 table for users (director/actor) because what would happen if a director is also an actor like Quentin Tarantino who appears in most of his movies. You would have to repeat data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Try to bring your model up to BCNF or 4NF and you'll be Ok